# Why Realm stores values in wrong order?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have a response, I'm storing that response in realm database,
I got below response but it save in the incorrect order.

It saves in realm in like below,

```
 “appData3”
 “appData8”
 “appData4”
 “appData1”
 “appData7”
 “appData1”
 “appData6”
 “appData5”
```

response is like below

```
{
"data": {
"APP_DATA_1": {
"vValue": “appData1”
},
"APP_DATA_2": {
"vValue":“appData2”
},
"APP_DATA_3": {
"vValue": “appData3”
},
"APP_DATA_4": {
"vValue":“appData4”
},
"APP_DATA_5": {
"vValue": “appData5”
},
"APP_DATA_6": {
"vValue": “appData6”
},
"APP_DATA_7": {
"vValue": “appData7”
},
"APP_DATA_8": {
"vValue": “appData8”
}
}
}
```

I store value using below code

```
DataManager.shared.store(from: data.data.appData1)
DataManager.shared.store(from: data.data.appData2)
DataManager.shared.store(from: data.data.appData3)
DataManager.shared.store(from: data.data.appData4)
DataManager.shared.store(from: data.data.appData5)
DataManager.shared.store(from: data.data.appData6)
DataManager.shared.store(from: data.data.appData7)
DataManager.shared.store(from: data.data.appData8)



 func store<T>(from object: T) where T: Object {
     
        realmMainDB.beginWrite()
        
        realmMainDB.add(object, update: .all)
        
        try! realmMainDB.commitWrite()
    }
```

if you want any related code let me,
I appreciate another method or way to store that response.

or let me know if How can I can store that response in user defaults.
thank you

Comment: Please do not use User Defaults in this fashion, unless is for app user preferences. User Defaults were designed to store preferences; their preferred units of measurement or media playback speed. See [User Defaults](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults)

Comment: @Jay - can you explain a bit more, why we can't use UserDefaults to store json small data?

Comment: You can certainly do that as long as it's in-line with the intended use of User Defaults - read the link in my comment above. The way it's being used in the question appears to be to store dynamic app-level data, not preferences of how the user interacts with the app (the User Defaults). However that's not really clear so a possible incorrect assumption on my part.

Answer (score 0):

Realm Results objects do not have a guaranteed order so whether saving or retrieving you should not expect results to be in an kind of order.

List objects on the other hand do guarantee their order.

Of you want to order a Results object, include a property that ensures that ordering, and when retrieving the results, always [sorted(byKeyPath:](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm-sdks/swift/latest/Structs/Results.html#/s:10RealmSwift7ResultsV6sorted9byKeyPath9ascendingACyxGSS_SbtF) that field.

Ordering with a timestamp or date string is popular but it will depend on the use case.

A datestring can be in a yyyymmdd format, so update your models to include that propery

```
{
   "data": {
      "APP_DATA_1": {
         "vValue": “appData1”
         "datestring": "20210625"
   },
      "APP_DATA_2": {
         "vValue":“appData2”
         "datestring": "20210525"
   },
```

when when reading

```
let results = realm.objects(DataClass.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "datestring", ascending: true)
```

The other advantage of this is when new data is added, it will be reflected in the results in the correct order.

Comment: I'm totally agree to use sorted(KeyPath:) but I can't include any new property incoming response, I mean I have to go with what I show in json response.

can you tell me how any hint or idea, so I can apply.

Comment: @Dhiren If you have no property to sort by then Realm will return unsorted results by it's nature. In some cases it may be sorted, but in other cases it may not. You should determine how you want the data sorted and include that clause `.sorted(byKeyPath: "vValue"` for example.

Comment: it gives incorrect order even use "vValue" for sorting.

Comment: @Dhiren It will sort the data by the value of the vValue property and will always be correct. Can you provide existing sample data, your code that filters it by vValue and then what the final output is? Please update the question with that information to clarify what the issue is. Keep in mind that sorting by Strings can be tricky when it comes to strings with numbers; 0, 1, 2, 3, 10, 21 will sort as 0, 1, 10, 2, 21, 3 as sorting is done lexicographically.

Comment: It saves in realm in like below, ALWAYS!!

 “appData3”
 “appData8”
 “appData4”
 “appData1”
 “appData7”
 “appData1”
 “appData6”
 “appData5”

Comment: @Dhiren Take a moment and re-read my above comments. Realm objects are **unordered** so regardless of what order they are saved in, what's important is they *read* in the correct order and that's done using a `sorted(byKeyPath` when reading them in. Again, take a look at my answer and they guarantees the objects are always sorted in the way you want.